# Deserialized object other than original serialized object

Tags: c#, serialization

I am using ASP Net Core 2.2

I seralize this dynamic object

```
var stuff1 = new
{
    Name = "John",
    Surname = "Smith",
    Addresses = new[] {
new { City = "New York", State = "NY"},
new { City = "Milano", State = "IT" }
};
var stuff1Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stuff1)
```

This is the serialized object:

```
{"Name":"John","Surname":"Smith"}
```

Now, I get this string and I deserialized it

```
dynamic stuff1Deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stuff1Serialized);
```

I expect that sutff1 and stuff1Deseralized has the same strucure, but they are different, why?

In Immediate window:

```
stuff1.name
"Jhon"

stuff1Deserialized.Name
{John}
    First: '((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)stuff1Deserialized.Name).First' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    HasValues: false
    Last: '((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)stuff1Deserialized.Name).Last' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    Next: null
    Parent: {"Name": "John"}
    Path: "Name"
    Previous: null
    Root: {{
  "Name": "John",
  "Surname": "Smith"
}}
    Type: String
    Value: "John"
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
```

I use the object with this simple DotLiquid template:

```
Hello {{Name}} {{Surname}}. Number of Addresses: {{Addresses.size}} - {{Addresses[0].City}} - {{Addresses[1].City}}
```

With stuff1 object I got the exptected result:

```
Hello John Smith. Number of Addresses: 2 - New York - Milano
```

With stuff1Deserialized object I got this result:

```
Hello John Smith. Number of Addresses: 2 - -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update as per comment**

I find one way to do this:

1 - object dynamic sample:

```
dynamic dynamicStuff = new
{
    Name = "John",
    Surname = "Smith",
    Obj = new { City = "New York", State = "NY" },// i add this to test object
    Addresses = new[]
    {
        new { City = "New York", State = "NY"},
        new { City = "Milano", State = "IT" }
    }
};
```

2 - serializing and deserializing to build dynamic object:

```
dynamic dynamicStuffDeSerialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicStuff));
```

3 - Converting `dynamic` object to `JObject` and building `Dictionary` Of (string, object) by converting `JObject` to `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> keyValuePairs = ConvertJObject(JObject.FromObject(dynamicStuffDeSerialized));

private static Dictionary<string, object> ConvertJObject(JObject jObject)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var property in jObject)
    {
        if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            keyValuePairs.Add(property.Key, ConvertJArray(property.Value.Select(o=>(JObject)o)));

        else if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            keyValuePairs.Add(property.Key, ConvertJObject((JObject)property.Value));

        else
            keyValuePairs.Add(property.Key, property.Value.ToString());
    }

    return keyValuePairs;
}

private static List<Dictionary<string, object>> ConvertJArray(IEnumerable<JObject> jObjects)
{
    return jObjects.Select(o => ConvertJObject(o)).ToList();
}
```

Note That, you can use `ToObject` to convert `JObject` To `Dictionary`, but it's convert just the simple value not object or array, like:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.FromObject(dynamicStuffDeSerialized);
Dictionary<string, object> dict = jObject.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

4 - use `Hash.FromDictionary` not `Hash.FromAnonymousObject`:

```
Template templatedynamicStuff = Template.Parse("Hello {{Name}} {{Surname}} City in Object {{Obj.City}}. Number of Addresses: {{Addresses.size}} - {{Addresses[0].City}} - {{Addresses[1].City}}");
string result = templatedynamicStuff.Render(Hash.FromDictionary(keyValuePairs));
```

Note that, i changed the `template` by adding `City in Object {{Obj.City}}`

5 - **TEST**

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

6 - **OUTCOMES**:

```
Hello John Smith City in Object New York. Number of Addresses: 2 - New York - Milano
```

**Old answers**

According to **newtonsoft** documentation, You can use [DeserializeAnonymousType](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) instead of `DeserializeObject` for *deserializing* Anonymous Object. but `DeserializeAnonymousType` needs a `definition` of *Anonymous* Type To get the same *object*.

Like the following code :

```
var stuff1 = new
{
    Name = "John",
    Surname = "Smith"
};

var stuff1Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stuff1);

var definition = new { Name = "", Surname = "" };
dynamic stuff1Deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(stuff1Serialized, definition);
```

**Update as per comment**

You can use `JObject` or `ExpandoObject` to get properties *names* and *values*, like the following code:

```
dynamic stuff1 = new
{
    Name = "John",
    Surname = "Smith"
};

var stuff1Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stuff1);

dynamic stuff1DeSerialized1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stuff1Serialized);

foreach (JProperty property in JObject.FromObject(stuff1DeSerialized1))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key:{property.Name}, Value:{property.Value}");
}

ExpandoObject stuff1DeSerialized2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(stuff1Serialized, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValue in stuff1DeSerialized2.ToList())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key:{keyValue.Key}, Value:{keyValue.Value}");
}
```

I hope to find other solution and share it with you.

Comment: Thank you Said. My problem is that i will receive a generic Json that I must pass to a DotLiquid method as anonymous object. I can't know in advance the type of the object

Comment: yeah , but how do you intend to consume this object if you do not know what parameters it has or is expected to have?

Comment: Thank you Said.
I must pass this object to DotLiquid, an html template engine that merge an html template with data.
You solution works for firse level properties. But if I add a child property, the childern nodes are not recognized by DotLiquid (see the update post).

Comment: Can you share your *template* used by *DotLiquid* please

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I updated my question with the simple template I use

Comment: @skysurfer, i'm adding a new solution, it's work fine. can you upvote and accept it if it's work for you :)

Comment: Thank you Said. You are great!!

Comment: @skysurfer, you're welcome. can you upvote and accept the answer, so that others would find it useful :)